# Separate/Move Child From Parents - CSS

Tags: css

Is there anyway in css to separate or move child from parents?

```
   <div id="parents">
        <div class="first-child">I am first-child</div>  
        <div class="second-child">I am second-child</div>  
   <div>
```

I want the second-child have the same role with parents.

Comment: Not possible in css

Comment: If you want the same styles as parent for the second child, you can use same classes for both.